# How to count li in jquery without image and via attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code . .

I have 3 `li` . . How can i count `li` that has no image and div style color is #c9c9c9?

in my case i have 1 `li` that has no image and div style color is #c9c9c9

so the output should be `1`

I don't have idea if this is possible.

This is my code:

```
<ul id="room_1">
        <li>
            <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#000000">
                <img src="images/leader.png">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#c9c9c9">
            </div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#000000">
            </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
```

This is my js:

```
alert($("ul li .wrap_body").length);
```

Comment: output should be two then if one has image then the remaining has no which is what you wanted to show

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8dutzetw/ just like answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the color style is an issue, to get `li`s without image you can use the [not](https://api.jquery.com/not) and [has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) like

```js
var $liswoimg = $('li').not(':has(img)');
snippet.log($liswoimg.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<ul id="room_1">
  <li>
    <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#000000">
      <img src="images/leader.png">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#c9c9c9"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#000000"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But if you can use the style attribute value then

```js
var $liswoimg = $('li:has(div[style="color:#c9c9c9"])').not(':has(img)');
snippet.log($liswoimg.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<ul id="room_1">
  <li>
    <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#000000">
      <img src="images/leader.png">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#c9c9c9"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#000000"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.filter()` , `is()`

```js
var li = $("#room_1 li").filter(function() {
  return $("> div[style=color\\:#c9c9c9]", this).is(function() {
    return !$("img", this).is("*")
  })
})
console.log(li.html(), li.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="room_1">
  <li>
    <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#000000">
      <img src="images/leader.png">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#c9c9c9">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#000000">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```